# Nginx fails to resolve Upstream React JS files and falls back to index.html

Tags: reactjs, angular, nginx, docker-swarm, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have docker swarm setup for a website. The main website is in Angular and specific portion of the website is React application.

The swarm cluster has 3 services for 3 apps. Both Angular and React apps  served through Nginx

1. Angular App (https://mywebsite.com)
2. React App (https://mywebsite.com/viewer)
3. Spring Boot app with `/api` end points (https://mywebsite.com/api)

Primary Nginx config that serves the website and Spring boot and React apps served as upstreams. Below Nginx file shows 3 location blocks for 3 apps.

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events
{
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http
{
    upstream springboot
    {
        server springboot:8081;
    }

    upstream viewer
    {
      server viewer;
    }

   # Redirect all requests to HTTPS server
    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name mywebsite.com;

        # redirects http requests to https
        return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    }

  server
  {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/mywebsite_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/mywebsite_com.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/mywebsite_com_truster_chain.crt;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /
    {
      #### Gzip Settings  ####
      gzip on;
      gzip_min_length   1100;
      gzip_vary         on;
      gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
      gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
      gzip_comp_level   5;

      #### Serve Angular Application ####
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }

   location /viewer
    {
      proxy_pass http://viewer;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api
    {
      proxy_pass http://springboot;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 30m;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**nginx.conf** (React)

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

The angular app and `/api/` paths work fine. But when I try to go to https://mywebsite.com/viewer path, the JS files are being rendered. Only `index.html` file renders and rest of the JS files could not be found and falls back to `index.html` which of course fails

**Error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.init-service-worker.js:1 
        
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. vendors~app.bundle.9…07e3ba0a6ba969.js:1 
        
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the issue was with Nginx. Rewriting URL after `/viewer/` fixed the issue

```
rewrite ^/viewer(/.*)$ $1 break;
```

here is the complete **Nginx** file

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    rewrite ^/viewer(/.*)$ $1 break;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Comment: may i ask where is the /50x.html located in the file folder? does it reside in  /usr/share/nginx/html; ?